"too large a matrix for LINPACK" when fitting a generalized ordered probit/logit model in R with large dataset
I'm working with a large dataset of around 5,000,000 observations, and I need to fit a generalized ordered probit or logit model using R. Here’s the code that I'm currently running:
library(dplyr)
library(ordinal)

# Set working directory and load data
setwd("...Hostels/R")
data <- read.csv(".../data_full.csv")

options(qr.LAPACK = TRUE)

# Convert character columns to factors
data$guest_country_name <- as.factor(data$guest_country_name)
data$unique_booking_id <- as.factor(data$unique_booking_id)

# Compute the number of reviews by guest_country_code
data <- data %>%
  group_by(guest_country_code) %>%
  mutate(nreviews = n()) %>%
  ungroup()

# Compute the number of different nationalities staying in a room
data <- data %>%
  group_by(unique_booking_id, guest_country_name) %>%
  mutate(unique_tag = row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(unique_booking_id) %>%
  mutate(num_nationalities = sum(unique_tag)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Apply combined filter condition
min_nreviews = 50
min_nationalities = 70
data <- data %>% filter(nreviews >= min_nreviews & num_nationalities >= min_nationalities)

# Define the countries and reference country
countries_all <- c("Algeria", "Argentina", "Australia", ..., "Ukraine", "United_Arab_Emirates", "United_Kingdom")

# Create dummy variables for each country
for (c in countries_all) {
  data[[c]] <- as.numeric(data$guest_country_name == c)
}

# Convert unique_booking_id to a factor
data$unique_booking_id <- as.factor(data$unique_booking_id)

# Ensure that the 'score' variable is an ordered factor
data$score <- as.ordered(data$score)

# Construct the formula for the model
formula <- as.formula(paste("score ~", paste(c(countries_all, "unique_booking_id"), collapse = " + ")))

# Fit the cumulative link model with nominal effects for countries
model <- clm(formula, nominal = as.formula(paste("~", paste(countries_all, collapse = " + "))), data = data)

# Print the model summary
summary(model)

When I run this code, I encounter the following error:
Error in qr.default(X, tol = tol, LAPACK = FALSE): 
  too large a matrix for LINPACK.

I’m using a computer with 128GB of memory, so I’m surprised to be hitting this limit. Is there a way to bypass or resolve this error while keeping the model structure intact?
Additional Information:

The score variable is an ordered factor.
The dataset includes a large number of dummy variables for different countries.
The error suggests that the design matrix might be too large to handle.

Any advice on how to handle this issue, either by optimizing the model fitting process or by using alternative methods or packages, would be greatly appreciated!

This post suggests that the solution is setting LAPACK = TRUE in qr. You should use traceback() after the error to identify which function contains the qr call. Then you can use trace(ordinal:::<name of the function>, edit = TRUE) to change (the default) LAPACK = FALSE to TRUE.

Of course, you should consider if a mixed effects model could be an alternative. If you include the countries as random effect(s), the design matrix gets much smaller.

And finally, it might be sufficient to fit the models to a subsample of your data.
